# PHP Array Turns me banging my head

Tags: php, arrays

I have some variables that I retrieve withem some data from the database like so:

```
foreach ($row as $result) {
    if ($row[28] == '') {
        $string28 = '';
    }else if( $row[28] == 0){
        $string28 = '';
    } else{
        $string28 = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Connexion</h1><img src="images/'.$row[28].'.jpeg"></div>';
    }
}


foreach ($row as $result) {
    if ($row[30] == '') {
        $string30 = '';
    }else if($row[30] == 0){
        $string30 = '';
    } else{
        $string30 = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Fixation</h1><img src="images/'.$row[30].'.jpeg"></div>';
    }
}

foreach ($row as $result) {
    if ($row[31] == '') {
        $string31 = '';
    }else if($row[31] == 0){
        $string31 = '';
    } else{
        $string31 = '<div class="add_img"><h1>Schéma</h1><img src="images/'.$row[31].'.jpeg"></div>';
    }
}
```

and here's the show results code:

```
<h1>Application</h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="add_div">
<?php
echo $string28;
echo $string29;
echo $string30;
echo $string31;
echo $string34;

?>
```

**But I can't code this expression with php**
**First I want to store all the variables in an array an then say if the array is empty *here we are talking about if all te variables are empty* then echo the espression *There's nothing***

Hope you can Help Me Guys.
And thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: Tip: If you have variables like `string28` and `string31` you're probably doing it wrong. It's a common code smell.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you exactly?  What troubleshooting did you do?  Are your return values as expected from `mysqli_query` or whatever you're using?  Are these two pieces of code even on the same page?

Comment: Please take another look to the post I'have edited the expression

Comment: So the goal is to see if $string28 (etc) is empty, and if so, remove the head tag? (What head tag? Where? What variables exactly do you want to know if they are empty?) Your question is super confusing. Please edit it to be as crystal-clear as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but to tell if a variable is empty, just use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(empty($string28)) {
   // do something since it's empty
}
```

It will work on arrays as well ...

```
$array = array();
if(empty($array)) {
   echo "Yep, it's empty!";
}
```

Comment: I want to tell if array is emty

Comment: `empty()` is a function, not an operator.

Comment: Note that `empty()` not only tests for an empty string (`''`), but for 0 and NULL.  This may be important if you store numbers or NULLs in your table.  Also, I'm not sure if an array is empty if it contains items that are empty (e.g. `$row[20]='';`).

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst empty() isn't a function. It's a language construct.